# How to access 'WindowsPreview' namespace?

Tags: c++, kinect

I am trying to work with a kinect 2 in c++. All the code samples I have seen use the WindowsPreview namespace but I don't seem to have access to it. I have the SDK (code samples run fine). I have correctly linked to the Kinect.h and kinect20.lib files. Can someone help me out?

[image: example of the error]

Comment: _"but I don't seem to have access to it"_ Sample code and error messages please, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Sorry, I added an example of the error.

Comment: Is it used the same way as in the samples you had compiled successfully? Does your project have all the same settings (include and library paths)? Is it an intellisense error only or doesn't the project compile? For the latter case, compile your project once, to update the indexer.

Comment: Compilation gives the same error. Other project settings are the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: Some `#define` (`-D` option) missing to activate the `WindowsPreview` may be? The information you give in your question isn't really sufficient to diagnose your error.

Comment: @CVirtuous: Namespaces have nothing to do with libraries (i.e. .lib files), they are supposed to be defined in plain text, openly in header files. So, all you need to do is search through your header files for the definition of `WindowsPreview::Kinect` namespace. If it is not there, then it won't work. If it is there, you will see what else is necessary (like a `#define something` or such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowsPreview::Kinect is the namespace when using the Kinect API for the Windows Store, the other APIs use Microsoft::Kinect.

Found a mention of the namespaces in one of the videos: [Kinect Data Sources and Programming Model](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2/02) (starts at 20:00)

> Rob: In the store APIs, the namespace is WindowsPreview.Kinect?
> Jesse: (Yes)
> Rob: Can you talk about the other APIs?
> Jesse: In the other APIs, the namespace is Microsoft.Kinect, the WindowsPreview namespace is indicating that we are previewing the WinRT APIs for further inclusion in some form of Windows down the road.

It appears to be listed as WindowsPreview.Kinect in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.kinectsensor.aspx) but in my code (not targetting the Windows store) it shows up as Microsoft.Kinect:[image]
In my opinion, this is something that could be more clearly documented, but it is possible I'm just not looking in the right places.