# I am *not* missing an assembly or reference

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and I'm getting an error in my C# code that I can't figure out.  I'm working with the Microsoft Kinect SDK, but I'll keep it general.

I downloaded the SDK, and I can get the included sample programs to build and run.  But when I try to use the code in my own project, I get the

`Type or namespace name 'Kinect' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (Are you missing an assembly reference)`

error.

The thing is, I'm not missing an assembly or reference.  I have it added to the project's references, and the path is valid.  Also, the `using` statements at the top of the file will autocomplete to "Kinect" for me.  If I start typing `using Microsoft.`, `Kinect` will appear as an autocomplete option.

What are the steps to debugging an error such as this?  Could it be a 32/64 bit issue?  I tried using Dependency Walker to look at the Kinect DLL, and while it throws some errors (`Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.`), it doesn't show any issues that I don't see with other DLLs that I'm using successfully.

What are some other potential issues that might cause a problem with DLLs not being recognized?

Comment: Look in your references - click on reference and go to properties. Check the path to which it points. You may find it wrong

Comment: Are you compiling for a .NET version which includes "Client Profile" in its name?

Comment: I had a similar problem the other day after installing a NuGet package and the way i "solved" it was by closing down VS and re-opening it again. No more missing assemblies.

Comment: What time of project is this?  The Kinect namespace exists in different namespaces within the Kinect SDK based on the type of project.  It might be [WindowsPreview.Kinect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032467/how-to-access-windowspreview-namespace/31038462#31038462)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Try going to your project settings and verify the version of the `.NET` framework it uses.

The best to do is to choose the same version as the external libraries.
If it's a `client profile`, it will very often bring that exact problem. (I'm not sure what the client profile is, but I ended up never using it...)

2 - Check if any of your references got an exclamation mark.

Comment: References don't get exclamation mark for format compatibility. You will learn of it at runtime. Think about that you can build your project compatibly to references. It only cares for version, public key, signatures, etc at design time.

Comment: It's been a while since I don't play with this....so I'll just remove the bit comment, thanks....

Comment: It was the .NET version, thank you.  The Kinect DLL was built on 4.5, and the rest of my program was 4.0.  When I changed my program to 4.5 it worked.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for this - bad target version was my problem with the Microsoft.Practices EnterpriseLibrary as well.