# how to use namespace of another project in my unit test so I can access and create a particular class

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

My unit test project, project name is "Alexander.Exercises.UnitTestProject1"

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; using Modules;

namespace UnitTestProject1 {
    [TestClass]
    public class ExerciseTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var d = new Fight();
        }
    } }
```

this is my other project with class Fight, project name is "Alexander.Exercises.Modules"

```
namespace Modules
{
    public class Fight
    {
    }
}
```

both projects are in one solution called "Alexander.Exercises"
I have made reference from Alexander.Exercises.UnitTestProject1 to Alexander.Exercises.Modules, and still I can't find a using with name Modules it says the type or name "Modules" cannot be found, I tried writing using Alexander.Exercises.Modules and everything but still does not work help please

I tried writing using Alexander.Exercises.Modules and everything but still does not work help please

Comment: I had it set up like this: `using mylib; using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` Maybe it's a name clash. The rest is more or same like yours.

Comment: I don't know what to do I tried everything but I can't still use a Class from another projects in my Unit Test project, for some reason If I try to use the class Fight in my main Program and I add using Modules it works fine, but when I try it in the UnitTest project I cannot.

Comment: It may sound dumb, but have you built the module and added its debug version to the references? Maybe it's a hickup related to the name 'Modules'. Try it with a different name, close and reopen all projects, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058288/i-am-not-missing-an-assembly-or-reference

Comment: Last one, it does not suffice to just add a `using` directive for your module, you also have to add a reference to the exact DLL that contains it. I think this was right-click on References and Add reference.